# for update record using sharepoint 2010 Timer job

Tags: timer-jobs

i want to know that how to update record in  MS sql server 2012 using SharePoint 2010 Timer job.Or how to call MS Sqlserver procedure using sharePoint timer job every hours.
Please help me any body,this is very urgent.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of resources online about how to create timer jobs for sharepoint like [this one](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/) and also from Microsoft in the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx)

What you would have to do is to replace the content of the Execute method with your custom code to update the SQL database.

And in the EventReceiver that installs the Timer Job you should do an new SPHourlySchedule (that schedules the timer job to be executed hourly)

For an extremly detailed guide to how you can create and deploy Timer Jobs I would recommend [this blogpost](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/)

As you can see, there are many steps involded, each probably already well documented both here on stackexchange and on different blogs. But I think that the last blogpost really teaches you the basics.

For more information about how to update the SQL database i recommend you to just google terms like "update SQL database from C#" or variants on the same theme.